# How to mock AWS API using Mockito in java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mockito

I need help to mock AWS APIs using Mockito in Java. As I have tried to mock RDS connection but connection returns null statement object. I have to mock S3, AWS Data pipeline, `JavaSaprkContext`, RDS connection, Lambda, SNS and DynamoDB.

Here is my code for RDS Connection, that returns null statement object:

```
public void testGetRDSConnection() throws SQLException{
    Connection connection = mock(Connection.class);
    Statement stmt = null;
    stmt = connection.createStatement(); // Get NULL statement Object
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table");
    if (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println("+ve Test is PASSED Name = testGetRDSConnection ");
    } else {
        System.out.println("+ve Test is FAILED Name= testGetRDSConnection ");
    }

}
```

and test case for S3, that return null metadata object:

```
 public void testGetObjectMetadata(){
    ObjectMetadata obj = S3Util.getObjectMetadata(mock(AmazonS3Client.class), bucketName, filePath);
    if (obj == null) {
        System.out.println("+ve Test is FAILED Name= 'testGetObjectMetadata()' No metadata found");
        fail("+ve Test is FAILED Name= 'testGetObjectMetadata()' No metadata found");

    } else if (obj != null) {
        System.out.println("+ve Test is FAILED Name= 'testGetObjectMetadata()'");

    }
}
```

Comment: Your first test is a unit test that is designed to test `Statement`. Your second test is a unit test that is designed to test `S3Util`. Neither of these, I assume, is code that you own.

Comment: In other words, neither of the pieces of code you've provided have a Test Subject. What is the target of your test? Neither test you have provides any sort of target aside from API code, which shouldn't be the stuff that needs checking.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to [whummer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41580552/750510) and [shachar's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37952667/750510) answers:

If you're a lucky JUnit 5 user, let me recommend you [JUnit 5 extensions for AWS](https://madhead.github.io/aws-junit5/asciidoc)*, a few JUnit 5 extensions that could be useful for testing AWS-related code. These extensions can be used to inject clients for AWS service clients provided by tools like localstack (or the real ones). Both AWS Java SDK v 2.x and v 1.x are supported.

**I maintain this library*

Answer (score 4):

[Never mock APIs/types](http://www.davesquared.net/2011/04/dont-mock-types-you-dont-own.html) that you don't know how they behave. A better solution will be to add your own API that one of its implementation will be AWS. Then you be able to mock your own API

Comment: Can you please  share a piece of code that illustrate your comment using any AWS service

Comment: Does'nt that shift the problem only one level further?

Answer (score 4):

There are some pretty sophisticated Cloud service mocking frameworks out there, for instance [moto](https://github.com/spulec/moto) has a mock implementation whose functionality is very similar to the actual S3 API.

You could also take a look at [LocalStack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack), a framework which combines existing tools and provides a fully functional local cloud environment that can be used for integration testing.

Although some of these tools are written in other languages (Python, Node.js), it should be easy to spin up the test environment in an external process from your Java test class.